# If - else php query

Tags: php, navigation, if-statement

I need a code that pulls out the listings count for a product in order to have them in the navigation. I am trying to get the product and listing number in the navigation (if there is any), but I don't want to display something if the listings count is equals to 0.

Here follows my code:

```
<?php if($listingsCount = getListingsCount(0,0,2,2,1,86) > 0): ?>
<a href="">Bakery</a>
<?php echo $listingsCount['totalRecords'] ?>.
<?php else: ?>
```

Comment: If you don't want to do anyting in the `else` case, just replace `else:` by `endif;`

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
if ( ($listingsCount = getListingsCount(0,0,2,2,1,86)) > 0)
```

In this case you the assignment is done first and is then compared to `0`. So `$listingCount` contains the real count.

The way you did it, the comparison is done first and the return value (`true/false`) is assigned to `$listingCount`.

Nevertheless. If you never reach the `else`-part, maybe something in your method `getListingsCount()` is broken.

Comment: And because `$listingsCount` seems to be an array, you would `sizeof()` to compare it to `0`.

Comment: @Jens - I thought this at first too, but maybe the OP's method `getListingsCount()` is doing some magic, like removing duplicates or some'. So it might return a different value than `count()/sizeof()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php if (($listingsCount = getListingsCount(0,0,2,2,1,86)) > 0) { ?>
<a href="">Bakery</a>
<?php echo $listingsCount['totalRecords']; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
Other text
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your answers. managed to get it working with this...

```
<?php 
$listingsCount = getListingsCount(0,0,2,2,1,86);
if($listingsCount['totalRecords'] > 0): 
?>
<dd>
<a href="">Bakery</a>
[<?php echo $listingsCount['totalRecords'] ?>]
</dd>
<?php endif; ?>
```